Is there a malware problem with latest JT Alert?
I just went to update JTAlert 2.62.1 and when it finished downloading the built-in Windows scanner flagged it as malware, said there was a "severe" vulnerability in one of the DLLs in it, and deleted the installer.
So I grabbed 2.62.0 and that was fine -- no complaints from the scanner.
Anyone know any more about this?  False alarm or is there an actual problem?

JTAlert uses AutoIT, which is often used by virus writers. Each version must be submitted to Microsoft and added to the exclusion list.
Your choices are to wait for that or ignore the warning and install.
